# Making form's URL visible in all browsers

Tags: forms

I have this regular form:

```
<form action="" method="post"><input class="ssd" type="submit" value="Hello"></form>
```

According to my observation, when I placed my mouse over the form's button(did not click on it), I could only see it's URL address in IE9(explorer 9). I couldn't see the URL address with FireFox and Chrome when I placed my mouse over the same form. Anyone has got any ideas why? is there any special coding that I need to do in order to make it work for every browser? (I tried different computers, same result)

I

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `title` attribute in the form's `submit` button. It appears to work in Chrome and Safari... I haven't gotten around to trying it in Firefox.

You can even put a `title` attribute in the `form` tag itself, and it does the same job when no other elements are in the way.

Here's a little [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QwuEQ/) for your delectation.

Comment: That's nice, but I meant the URL address which is in the bottom of the browser. here is a picture: http://img577.imageshack.us/img577/6945/55555x.jpg - it works only on IE9.

Comment: Then the answer is probably no. You might try a JavaScript solution, but most browsers just ignore the attempt these days. There is certainly no way to alter the default behavior with HTML, and to be honest, the status bar is hidden be default for most browsers.